# How to resolve NaN:NaN:NaN error in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jenkins, firefox, nan

I'm currently working on below code, trying to retrieve **last success** and **last failure** dates from Jenkins. It works fine on chrome for both the dates but gives NaN error in firefox for **last success** date.

```
$.ajax({
                                                    type : "get",
                                                    url : 'getJobsSuccessdetails?jobname='+jobname,
                                                    data:{"username": $('#userName').val()},
                                                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                    traditional : true,
                                                    cache : false,
                                                    success : function(response) {
                                                        console.log("SUCCESS resposne = "+JSON.stringify(response));
                                                        var unixts = response[0].timestamp;
                                                        var date = new Date(unixts);
                                                        console.log("data.getDate() = "+date.getDate())
                                                        
                                                        var sDate = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' - ' + date.getUTCHours() + ':' + date.getUTCMinutes();
                                                        
                                                        console.log("data.getDate() = "+sDate);
```

**Expected result:**
Last Success ----> 07/01/2020 - 9:27

**Result:**
Last Success ----> an/an/Nan - Nan:Nan

Can anyone please help me with the code to resolve this issue?

Comment: that code works fine in all browsers when `date` is a **valid** date - you're probably constructing `date` in a way that ONLY chrome (and it's offspring) recognises rather than the correct way as per specification ... show how `date` is created - [new Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters)

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for your response, I've added full code above. Could you please check.

Comment: what is the value of `response[0].timestamp` - is it a string in a format that is universally accepted as per the documentation I linked to?

Comment: @Bravo "Please consider adding a comment below if you think the post below can be improved."

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy - you're right ... Mabel updated the question after I pointed out that *you're probably constructing date in a way that ONLY chrome (and it's offspring) recognises* - and since then has refused to answer the simple question *what is the value of response[0].timestamp* - so, clearly does not want any help after all :p

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy - Also, before even knowing how the constructor is used, the fact that it works in Chrome (and its offspring) and not Firefox would suggest that `date.getDate()` etc is returning `NaN` - so, your answer would also result in `date.getDate()` etc returning `NaN` so, no amount of trickery can change `NaN`  to what it "should" be

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy, it didn't work out. Could you please suggest some another solution?

Comment: @Bravo Could you please suggest changes in the code as last failure date is working fine on firefox. If you need I could add the "last failure" code.

Comment: nope - no idea what data yu're trying to use for the date

Comment: Hi @Mabel.  Apologies for the delayed reply.  As Bravo mentioned - need a little more info.  I'd be happy to help though.  I'd be happy to do a Skype session, Zoom session, Google chat, etc. however you can screen share your code so I can see what you're seeing. Please let me know if that would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring the date as a date object and placing a space on both sides of the minus sign got this to work for me:

```
var date = new Date();

var sDate = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + 
            ("0" + (date.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" +
            date.getFullYear() + " - " + 
            date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes();

console.log(sDate); // Last Success --> 08/09/2022 - 5:59
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll try it.

Comment: @Mabel - sounds good!   Please let me know how it goes - happy to help with whatever I can.  :  )

Comment: @Bravo "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved."

Comment: if `date` value is `InvalidDate` ... nothing will recover the date required - the issue in the question is that `date` constructor fails

Comment: @bravo. thanks for clarifying!  :  )  When Mabel initially posted (before editing/updating her post) neither var unixts = response[0].timestamp; nor var date = new Date(unixts); were included in her original post.  I'm not sure that suggesting she declare a date object correctly was incorrect on my part. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: that's irrelevant - spaces in a string won't change date.getDate() from NaN to a number

Comment: When using strings that can be evaluated to numbers with mathematical operators, you’ll find that JavaScript will implicitly convert the strings to numbers